# cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (1,28,28,1)

Tags: python, deep-learning

During the classification of MNIST data, I am not able to upload the custom image from myself and gives
ValueError **cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (1,28,28,1)**

```
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
   path = '/content/' + fn
   img = image.load_img(path, target_size =(28, 28))
   x = image.img_to_array(img)
   x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
   images = np.vstack([x])
   print(images.shape)
   images = images.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
   print(images.shape)
   classes = model.predict(images, batch_size = 10)



Capture.PNG(image/png) - 8252 bytes, last modified: 1/26/2020 - 100% done
Saving Capture.PNG to Capture (1).PNG
(1, 28, 28, 3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-810149b1d6fd> in <module>()
     13   images = np.vstack([x])
     14   print(images.shape)
---> 15   images = images.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)
     16   print(images.shape)
     17   classes = model.predict(images, batch_size = 10)

 ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2352 into shape (1,28,28,1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably are trying to predict on an RGB image, while the model requires a grayscale image. What would work is if you do

```
img = img[:,:,0]
```

right after you load the image and then do the remaining process as it is.

Comment: I added this right after the image gets loaded - as you suggest - but I get a 'TypeError: Image object is not subscriptable'

Comment: Ok I see now, `img = img[:,:,0]` needs to be placed after image is represented as an array.